# "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break" error under php 7.3

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.3

I install laravel 5.8 on new Ubuntu 16 instance under Digital Ocean.
I need to install php 7.2 and for this I run commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get remove php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

I was very surprosed that I found php 7.3:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.3.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  3 2019 10:00:05) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

After that I got error on composer installing:

```
# composer  install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file


  [ErrorException]                                                                         
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

Googling I found that it is some specific php7.3 error and I wonder which can be decision here?
To downgrade to php7.2(If yes how better to make it?)

Or some other decision ?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Composer are you running?

Comment: According to https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7783, this has been fixed since Composer 1.6.0

Comment: looks like it is very low : Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34  .  How to raise it?

Comment: There's install instructions [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Comment: I run 4 commands : php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" and restarted apache.  But version of composer is the same. What else I missed ?

Comment: Sounds like you're still running 7.3 on the command line. You can switch to 7.2 by running `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2`, then do a `composer install` again

Comment: Running
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
I got in console:
# php -v
PHP 7.2.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  3 2019 09:23:41) ( NTS )

but phpinfo in browser shows :
PHP Version 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

How to refresh it?

Comment: I found this 
https://medium.com/andrewmmc-io/upgrade-php-version-to-7-2-from-7-0-c005a0926642
instruction but got error in console :
# apt-get install php7.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.2 is already the newest version (7.2.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
?

Comment: Im not sure that the version of the php/composer it is the problem... I have latest on both but Im still getting that error.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to PHP 7.3, try,

```
  sudo wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.0/composer.phar -O /usr/local/bin/composer && sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

It's just the version dependency. PHP 7.3

and `composer update` works!